RabbitMQ not starting after specifying database
I've installed RabbitMQ on Ubuntu. When installed, it is starting well. But when I add database in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:
database.dir = /data/rmq
log.dir = /data/rmq/log

then:
sudo chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /data/rmq
sudo chmod 750 /data/rmq

it gives error:
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xeu rabbitmq-server.service" for details.

I'm not getting anything substantial in error logs.
I can't find anything in documentation

See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xeu rabbitmq-server.service" for details.
